# Join with any terminated thread

Tags: c, linux, unix, networking, pthreads

I'm writing a pthreaded network application (in C) and was thinking that I should create a thread to handle each incoming connection. However, I can't get my head around which design I should use, since I must limit the number of connections to a fixed number (say, 5).

While reading the man pages for pthread_join I found:

```
There is no pthreads analog of waitpid(-1, &status, 0), that  is,  "join  with  any terminated
thread". If you believe you need this functionality, you probably need to rethink your
application design.
```

Why is this? And how could I accomplish my goal?
Thanks

Comment: Have you considered just using non-blocking I/O on your sockets (perhaps with poll, epoll, or select) and just having one-thread for all connections?  You can definitely scale better than 5 connections with this approach - and it's not hard.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good question.

I think the standard reasoning the man page author is getting at is that processes need to be reaped with `waitpid` or they leave resources hanging in their wake.  That's not really the case with pthreads.  If you don't need know when a specific thread terminates (or have no need for its return code) you can just make it a detached thread; it ends and that's that.  Conversely, if you really need to join with a thread you should know which one you need to join with.

Thinking about it further, there is a direct one-to-many relationship between a parent process and its children.  `Waitpid` will wait on its children and the OS will keep track of those children and deliver them to the parent.  This will happen regardless of how many generations of the process are created - the parent reaps its children.

In a threaded program any thread can create other threads.  What would a catchall `pthread_join` mean in this instance?  If all threads are meant to be joined with this one catchall thread then all is fine.  But what about programs where some thread really needs to be joined with its child threads while it is ok for the remainder of the threads to be joined by the catchall?  How does the OS or pthreads keep track of which `join` applies in each case without building in a substantial infrastructure?

I suppose that's possible and I imagine everyone has had occasion to wish there was a generic `waitpid` analog in pthreads but it might be a lot of overhead for what is, in practice, mostly an annoyance.  When you find yourself in the situation where you have multiple threads to join but you don't know which is going to end first you can build a queue (or use a pipe or whatever) and have the dying thread indicate it should be joined with.

Answer (score 0):

If you're putting a limit on the number of concurrent threads, your best bet is to often create *all* the threads (workers) up front and have them run in an infinite loop, waiting for work on a queue.

Then the main thread is responsible for adding work items (connections in this case) to that queue for the workers to process.

The advantage of this is simplicity and speed. Simplicity because you never have to worry about threads starting or stopping except once, they're always running, and servicing work items.

Speed for the same reason. It's like a fixed size thread pool. It also processes work items in the most efficient way (workload is automatically balanced by virtue of the fact a thread will ask for a new item only when, and as soon as, it's finished the previous one).

In pseudocode, this would be something like the following. The mainline simply adds work items to the queue as they come in. Once it's finished everything, it can post a special finishing work item for each thread then wait for them all to finish.

```
def queue workqueue = empty

def main:
    # start the threads

    create threadId[5]
    for each threadId (i):
        threadId[i] = startThread (worker)

    # main work loop, finished with (for example) external signal.

    while not finished:
        get workitem from some source
        add workitem to workqueue

    # Place one special FINISH work item for each thread.

    for each threadId (i):
        add FINISH item to workqueue

    # Wait for all threads to exit, then exit main.

    for each threadId (i):
        wait for threadId[i] to exit

    exit
```

The worker threads are similarly simple. An infinite loop to get the work items as needed and process them.

If the work item is a finishing one, it exits, guaranteeing that each thread gets one and only one finishing work item:

```
def worker:
    # Simple infinite loop to get work items.

    while true:
        get workitem from workqueue

        # Exit if told to.

        if workitem is a FINISH item:
            break

        # Otherwise, process the item and loop around to request next.

        process workitem

    exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to first echo paxdiablo's suggestion that you allow your threads to remain persistent, rather than allowing them to terminate and relaunching them. In addition, I echo selbie's suggestion to use non-blocking I/O, but I would couple it with your fixed threads (I would think just 1 per CPU). Using both allows you to achieve a much higher workload and maximize your machine's CPU resources.

To answer your question, though, if you want to be able to join with the threads in termination order, you need the threads to communicate with the reaper their order of termination. This can be done relatively simply with a `pipe`. When a thread terminates, it writes its `tid` to the the pipe, and the reaper reads the `tid` and does the `pthread_join`.

```
int tid_pipe[2];
pipe(tid_pipe);

void * thread_proc (void *arg) {
    /* ... */
    /* thread exiting */
    pthread_t me = pthread_self();
    write(tid_pipe[1], &me, sizeof(me));
    return 0;
} 

/* thread reaper */
while (read(tid_pipe[0], &tid, sizeof(tid)) == sizeof(tid)) {
    pthread_join(tid, &retval);
    /* ... */
}
```

But, as an alternative, you could allow your threads to run detached, and not worry about joining. Instead, you can use a condition variable to allow your main thread to know when it is okay to launch another thread.

```
void * thread_proc (void *arg) {
    pthread_detach(pthread_self());
    /* ... */
    /* thread exiting */
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
    if (thread_count++ == 0) pthread_cond_signal(&c);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
    return 0;
}

/* thread spawner */
while (waiting_for_work()) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m);
    while (thread_count == 0) pthread_cond_wait(&c, &m);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m);
    /* ... handle work with new thread ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since threads are not organized in a hierarchy as are processes, waiting for "any" thread  would imply that any thread had access to global information about all threads. Organizing such information in some sort of data structure (or whatever) would be a certain overhead, since all thread creation and termination would have to pass by there. This kind of overhead is voluntarily avoided, threads are meant to be lightweight and fast.

There is also the other aspect that there are threads that can't even be joined, namely those that have detached or that were detached from the start. Imposing such overhead to them would even less be acceptable.

Answer (score -1):

If it's a multithreaded server with one thread per client, just count 'em out and count 'em back in again.  Use atomic inc/dec of a 'clientCount' int on client thread creation, (ie. in accept() thread), and just before client-server threads exit, and don't accept() any more connections if the count >5, (ie. issue a 'Too many connections, try later' page directly from the accept() thread instead of creating a new server-client thread).

Try to forget about 'Join' - just imagine you never read about it.